# ServiceNow Single-Log-Out (ADFS) redirects back to ServiceNow and logs you in again

Tags: logout, saml-2.0, adfs, servicenow

We have ServiceNow among other applications configured in ADFS for SSO, ServiceNow is the only app using SP Initiated signon however.
Sometimes when you log out, it behaves as it should and goes to https://adfs.example.com.au/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0 and tells you that you are signed out but sometimes instead of going to the signed out page you just get redirected back to ServiceNow, (you can see another SAML request happening and it lets you in) and your session is still logged in. Obviously this represents a security issue! The User logs out then leaves the machine without looking and the session is still open!

Anyone come across this before? It seems SP Initiated Sign On is buggy and I need to fix these log out issues for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The wa=wsignout1.0 is intended to use for wsfed applications. servicenow as a SAML2 app should be sending a properly constructed samlp:logoutrequest to the /adfs/ls endpoint to do a signout properly.